# How to remove footer from wordpress "powered by wordpress"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wonder how can I remove footer which contains "powered by wordpress". I've setup this page and in the bottom of it you can see "powered by wordpress".
[Web page](http://romanpolak.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The footer provides html class.

```
class="site-info"
```

so i edited css file as that

```
.site-info { 
display: none; 
}
```

Comment: I think that's what I said? Well more, or less. There's much less point hiding the div than simply _hiding_ it using css?

Comment: You could also delete it with jQuery. `jQuery( '.site-info' ).remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Very likely edit the footer.php file in your themes directory